React native installtion isssu
I am setting react-native environment for window operation sysyem. I have followed installtion instructions according to official documentaions. After following all instructions when I finally try to run my app using command "npm run adroid". When i put the command then following screen appears.
I have tried command "npm react-native doctor". It shows that all the dependencies are installed.

You did not include an error message or the screen that appears when you try running the app.
